# How to make bootbox inside modal dialog?

Tags: modal-dialog, bootbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXnFL.png)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ajax" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-center">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Ajax Content</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="form" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">English：</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" name="en_key" value="" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn blue" onclick="saveParameter()">Commit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



function saveParameter(){
      bootbox.alert({
                  size: "small",
                  message: "Success!",
                });
}
```

Fist,I show the modal dialog, and click Commit button and alert bootbox,
But the bootbox is outside the modal dialog like the picture, How to make bootbox inside modal dialog ??

Comment: Are you using a library to create the modal?  Also, provide a code sample so others have a starting point to form an answer for you.

Comment: I have edit the question , and put same code sample

Comment: Multiple open dialogs are not supported by Bootstrap (which means it's also not supported by Bootbox).